# How to extract values from requests?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, request

I would like to extract the `division` data from the URL

`path("company/<division>/authenticate", views.user_info, name="user_info")`

I tried to do it like this but it doesn't work

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def user_info(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = {
            "username": request.GET.get("username"),
            "password": request.GET.get("password"),
            "division": request.GET.get("division"),
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What do you mean? What do you expect to happen? How does that differ from what is actually happening?

Comment: I get the `TypeError: user_info() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server'`

Comment: Then the problem is where you are *calling* the function. Somewhere you're doing `user_info(server=foo)` Please paste in the entire Traceback.

Comment: I don't think your `user_info` view is being called when you call that particular API since the view function missing the **`division`** keyword argument

Comment: I added the whole response to the question @That1Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is missing `division` keyword argument. Try this:

```py
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def user_info(request, division):
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = {
            "username": request.GET.get("username"),
            "password": request.GET.get("password"),
            "division": division,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```